# Recursion: Children are being added to wrong parents in iterative deepening depth first search

Tags: python, search, recursion, graph, graph-algorithm

`.getSuccessorStates(node)` returns the correct successor states (children). I have tested this method on its own using the graph provided in this problem. The problem lies when I add recursion to the mix for this iterative deepening depth-first search algorithm. When I check the value of the `self.parent` dictionary after everything has been returned in order to backtrack and find the shortest path, some nodes in the dictionary are matched with an incorrect parent. I'm 99% sure it has to do with recursion when I store `self[parent] = node`, because `getSuccessorStates` gives the correct children for the given node, but `self.parent` contains some values with wrong parent to children pairings. I'm wondering if I put `self.parent[child] = node` in the wrong place in the code?

```
def __init__(self, graph):
        self.graph = graph
        self.nodesCreated = 0
        self.maxFrontier = 0
        self.maxExplored = 0
        self.parent = {}

def recursive_depth_limited_search(self, node, limit):
    if node == self.getGraph().getGoalState():
        return node
    elif limit == 0:
        return "cutoff"
    else:
        cutoff_occurred = False
        for child in self.getGraph().getSuccessorStates(node):
            self.setNodesCreated(self.getNodesCreated() + 1)
            self.parent[child] = node
            result = self.recursive_depth_limited_search(child, limit - 1)
            if result == "cutoff":
                cutoff_occurred = True
            elif result != "No solution found":
                return result
        if cutoff_occurred:
            return "cutoff"
        else:
            return "No solution found"
```

Comment: Please supply a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The logic appears sound -- as far as I can see it.